# Java: Linked list node isn't working in my code

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, nodes

So I am very very at linked list and creating nodes is very confusing. for my program, I have to create a method in main class called insertAfter(TrackerNode nodeLoc) that refers to another class I have created for inserting data in node. The user inputs are initially, a total number of nodes, then data for each node (name and age).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code as posted, the `age` field (according to your requested output) should be an `int` and you need to remember which order you declare `age` and `name` in your constructors. It is also possible to shorten the repetitive constructors with `this()`; and I would prefer using `toString()` over a custom data dumper method. Like,

```
public class TrackerNode {
    private int age;
    private String name;
    private TrackerNode nextNodeRef; // Reference to the next node

    public TrackerNode() {
        this("", 0);
    }

    public TrackerNode(String name, int age) {
        this(name, age, null);
    }

    public TrackerNode(String name, int age, TrackerNode nextLoc) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
        this.nextNodeRef = nextLoc;
    }

    public void insertAfter(TrackerNode nodeLoc) {
        TrackerNode tmpNext = this.nextNodeRef;
        this.nextNodeRef = nodeLoc;
        nodeLoc.nextNodeRef = tmpNext;
    }

    // Get location pointed by nextNodeRef
    public TrackerNode getNext() {
        return this.nextNodeRef;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s, %d", this.name, this.age);
    }
}
```

Then your `main` loop should actually use the `i` you read and you need to reset to the head node before you print. Something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

    // References for TrackerNode objects
    TrackerNode headNode = null, currNode = null, lastNode = null;

    // Scan the number of nodes
    int i = scnr.nextInt();

    // in data and insert into the linked list
    for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
        String name = scnr.next();
        int age = scnr.nextInt();
        scnr.nextLine();
        if (lastNode != null) {
            currNode = new TrackerNode(name, age);
            lastNode.insertAfter(currNode);
        } else {
            currNode = headNode = new TrackerNode(name, age);
        }
        lastNode = currNode;
    }

    // Print linked list
    currNode = headNode;
    while (currNode != null) {
        System.out.println(currNode);
        currNode = currNode.getNext();
    }
}
```

Which I tested with your provided input (and the output I received seems to match the posted expectations):

```
3
John
22
Silver
24
Smith
21
John, 22
Silver, 24
Smith, 21
```